# Django unittests mock.patch will not work if I import the function on top of the file

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing

Hello currently found a problem which I could not find solution to it.

I have a django application which communicates with external services in order to write unittests i must patch the functions which call the external services with `mock.patch`

```
#api_views.py
from examplemodule import examplefunction # just example

class GetSomeInfoFromExternalService(ApiView):
   def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if example_function(attrs) == somevalue:
           return Response({'detail':'OK'})
       return Response({'detail':'Not ok'})
```

here is my other file

```
#tests.py
from unittests import mock
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @mock.pach('examplemodule.examplefunction')
    def test_1(self):
        examplefunction.return_value=123
```

Like that the patch method will not work, but if I import the `examplefunction` inside the ApiView.get method is overriding and the mock works.

```
#api_views.py


class GetSomeInfoFromExternalService(ApiView):
   def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
   from examplemodule import examplefunction # If the import is here the override is working properly
       if example_function(attrs) == somevalue:
           return Response({'detail':'OK'})
       return Response({'detail':'Not ok'})
```

Comment: What if you mock like this: `api_views.examplefunction` ?

Comment: @Amin just tried it. It is not working

Comment: @Amin It is working <3